# Opportunity Costs and Trade conditions

Tags: microeconomics

A and B can both bake cakes or grow carrots such that they are each self sufficient, or they can each specialize in one activity and trade between themselves. Cakes and carrots are both desirable for both people. A spends 10 hours in a day and can bake 5 cakes or spends the same 10 hours and grows 25 carrots, while B spends 10 hours to bake 4 cakes or to grow 44 carrots. Which of the following is a specialization according to comparative advantage and an agreeable trade between both of them?
Select one:
a.

1. A bakes 5 cakes and gives 2 of them to B in exchange for 13 carrots from him
2. B grows 44 carrots and gives 22 of them to A in exchange for 1 cake
   from him
3. B grows 44 carrots and gives 22 of them to A in exchange for 1.5 cakes from him
4. A bakes 5 cakes and gives 1 of them to B in exchange for 13 carrots
   from him

I understand that the first stop calculating the opportunity costs for the two and then looking for a trade term between the two. That would imply that the answer is 1, but some sources I’ve consulted say that the answer is 4.